# Multi-platform chomp working on unix, windows and mac text files

Tags: perl

Looking for a way to chomp newline characters irrespective of the platform the files were created on.

The problem as specified by [perlport#newlines](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines) is that newlines are encoded differently on each platform:

\012 unix

\015\012 windows

\015 mac

However, chomp is platform specific and will only remove the character for the platform it's running on, or anything set by the `$/` variable.

So far I came up with the following regex that seems to be working:

```
# multiplatform chomp
s/\015?\012?$//;
```

Is that the correct solution or am I missing some cases and there's a better one?

Comment: If you're reading a file with `while (<FH>) {...}` you'll only get one line for a Mac file on a Unix system. So unless your chomp is purely for theoretical purposes, you'll have to split the file yourself into logical lines.

Comment: I thought Macs finally did things sanely now -- ie: the *nix way -- since OSX.

Comment: Yes, unless you are working with legacy systems and files, it would be pretty rare to see old-style Mac line endings now. And even in that case, I would simply convert the files to unix format first before processing them.

Comment: I hit that problem in CPAN testing. If you're releasing a module on CPAN and include a testing file with __DATA__ this becomes an issue.

Comment: It's been some time since Mac systems used \015 as a newline character. OSX is Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\v matches vertical white space, so you should be able to use

```
s/\v+$//;
```

However, this assumes that you don't mind cutting off things like form feeds and vertical tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use

```
 s/\s+$//;
```

Comment: This will also trim the line, but I can live with that, as it seems like a more elegant solution. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to catch all cases, your regex is fine for stripping newlines. But it's not ok for checking if a newline is there, it will happily match a line with no newline. For that you have to spell it all out.

```
m{(\015|\015\012|\012)\z};
```

Note the use of `\z`. This is because `$` will match a newline at the end of a line which will steal from the capture group.

Realistically, you don't need to worry about the "Mac" newline. The "Mac" newline refers to the pre-OS X MacOS. It's ***extremely*** unlikely you'll encounter a file from that era, and I say this as someone who still has a working [Mac SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_SE). So all you really need to worry about is the Windows and Unix newlines. That's typically done like so:

```
s{\015?\012\z}{};
```